# jQuery add class for certain time

Tags: jquery

How I can add a css class to an element for only 10 seconds ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A nicely reusable way would be this little jQuery plugin:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({ 

        addTemporaryClass: function(className, duration) {
            var elements = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                elements.removeClass(className);
            }, duration);

            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).addClass(className);
            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Use like so:

```
$("#myElement").addTemporaryClass("myClass", 10000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the class, then call `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 10000)` to remove it 10,000 milliseconds later.

Comment: you are correct, I removed my answer - should of JSFiddled earlier

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout(function,10000);` directly after you set the class on the element to remove the class from that element.

Answer (score -1):

You can add class , and remove it without **setTimeout()** like this.

```
$(".count-box", element).addClass("red");
$(".count-box", element).removeClass("red", 10000);
```

Comment: The second parameter in the "removeClass" method is the length of the animation, not the timeout length.